# Load audio to csv dataset under certain frequency range

Tags: python, dataset, signal-processing, mfcc

Hi i am working on extracting the MFCCs of audio files into a csv dataset. I am wondering how to only take audios with over 6000Hz. One possible way is to apply highpass filter, however, I don't know how to achieve it in python. Below is the code I have now:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directoryName):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'): 
       (rate,audio)=wavfile.read(filename)
        audio = highpass(audio, rate, 15, 6000)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(audio,rate,nfft=1200)
        fbank_feat = logfbank(audio,rate,nfft=1200)
        features = Recorder.mean_features(mfcc_feat)
```

So I want to achieve:

```
If the signal inside an audio file is over 6kHz, 
take the MFCCs of this audio and write into dataset;
else discard it.
```

Comment: Do you mean that the sample rate is above 6kHz? Or that there is energy in the audio above 6kHz?

Comment: @jonnor It's the energy in the audio above 6KHz. Sry for the misunderstandings.